# Совместить масштаб или совместить по оси w

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Рисую два графика с разными масштабами, но не получается совместить их по оси w. Надо совместить L(w) и -Fi(w) по принципу 0 = -pi. Рисую в python+matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def W(w):
    return 36.69487 / (0.00008214*(1j*w)**4 + 0.017538*(1j*w)**3  + 26.440677*(1j*w)**2 + (1j*w))

def A(w):
    resW = W(w)
    return np.sqrt(resW.real**2 + resW.imag**2)

def L(w):
    return 20*np.log10(A(w))

def Fi(w):
    resW = W(w)
    U, V = resW.real, resW.imag
    return np.arctan(V/U)

w = np.linspace(0.01, 1000, 1000)
wzero = np.zeros(w.shape)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax.plot(w, L(w),color='r')
ax1.plot(w,-Fi(w)-np.pi,color='b')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim([0.01,100])
ax.set_ylabel('L(w)')
ax1.set_ylabel('-Fi(w)')
```

[image: График]

Comment: По идее `ax.set_ylim` и `ax1.set_ylim` должны были помочь, но что-то никакого эффекта у меня не получилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если поместить начало координат для `ax` в середину оси?:

```
yabs_max = abs(max(ax.get_ylim(), key=abs))
ax.set_ylim(ymin=-yabs_max, ymax=yabs_max)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут суть в том, чтобы не только визуально это было, главное, чтобы можно было правильно определить места пересечений, в том числе с осью w